# Script para Refrescar una web

Tags: web, script

Me gustaría poder hacer un script que corra en mi ordenador, de forma que una página web (Digamos que habro un [www.google.es](http://www.google.es) y quiero refrescarla cada 10 segundos) se refresque (misma función que hacer F5) continuamente (cada 10 segundos digamos).

La pregunta va referida tan sólo a refrescar una web abierta en mi navegador. No a una web que yo creo y que lo programo en HTML.

Soy bastante nuevo en todo esto.

Lo que he intentado es esto en un archivo con extensión .PS1 (Para empezar, no se si es esta la extesión correcta o debería usar otra extensión). Tampoco tengo muy claro donde tengo que indicar la dirección de la web que quiero actualizar

```
//Función actualizar
<script type="text/javascript">
function actualizar(){location.reload(true);}
//Función para actualizar cada 5 segundos(5000 milisegundos)
setInterval("actualizar()",5000);
</script>
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problema específico has tenido? Por cierto, HTML no es un lenguaje de programación :) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Esto funciona (en teoría, no lo sé) sólo si uno usa un plugin como greasemonkey. Y tu script es javascript, no es ps1 (powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está correctamente, con él conseguirías refrescar la página. Sobre tu pregunta te comento 2 cosas:

1. Para que se ejecute el método debes llamarlo.
2. Ese código únicamente funcionará en el documento que lo hayas insertado. Es decir, que si quieres refrescar una página externa ajena a tu control no vas a poder con el código, porque no lo puedes instalar en su código fuente, y pese a que consiguieras ejecutarlo en la consola del navegador en su reinicio dejaría de funcionar.

Si únicamente quieres refrescar la página te recomiendo que habilites alguna extensión del navegador, como [Easy Auto Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=es) en chrome.

Comment: Hola, Muchisimas gracias. Efectivamente lo que buscaba es algo como Easy Auto Refresh. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Me alegro, suerte! 